# jQuery UI different drop events, depending on droppable class

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I have 2 different droppable classes. I want to perform different drop events (dropBar, dropTile) depending on which droppable class element was dropped on. Here is my code:

```
$(".droppable-tile").droppable({
      accept: '.draggable-task, .task, .daily-task',
      tolerance:  'pointer',
      hoverClass: "tile-draggable-hover",
      drop: dropTile 
    });
$(".droppable-bar").droppable({
      accept: '.draggable-task, .task, .daily-task',
      hoverClass: "tile-draggable-hover",
      tolerance:  'pointer',
      drop: dropBar
});
```

As you can see these 2 droppables are nearly identical, the only difference is the event drop. Is there a way to merge these droppable statements so as not to repeat the code? I need to add that in these ondrop functions I use event,ui, $(this) variables/keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".droppable-bar,.droppable-tile").droppable({
        accept: '.draggable-task, .task, .daily-task',
        hoverClass: "tile-draggable-hover",
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            // Check droppable element by class
            if ($(this).hasClass('droppable-tile')) {
                // your droppable-tile code
            }
            else if ($(this).hasClass('droppable-bar')) {
                // your droppable-bar code
            }
        },

    });
```

**[Online output (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/tkcqxggc/)**